# How to use Routes and Redirect from same npm package react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to use 3 things from react-router-dom to implement router in my application i.e. Routes, `useNavigate` and `Redirect`. But the problem is Routes and `useNavigate` is not available in react-router-dom 5.2.0. So, i installed react-router-dom v6.0.0-alpha.1 in order to use Routes and `useNavigate`. But the problem is Redirect is removed from react-router-dom v6.0.0-alpha.1. Now i don't understand how i am going to use Routes, `useNavigate` and `Redirect` under specific react-router-dom

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate, useLocation, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Loader } from "../common";
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-dnd";

const StudentList = lazy(() => import("../pages/StudentList"));
const About = lazy(() => import("../pages/About"));

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const currentModule = "/" + useLocation().pathname.split("/")[1];
  const onLoad = () => {
    navigate(currentModule);
  };

  useEffect(onLoad, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Routes>
          {[
            <Route
              key="/student"
              path="/studentlist/*"
              element={<StudentList />}
            />,
            <Route key="/about" path="/about/*" element={<About />} />,
            <Redirect key="redirect" from="/" to="/studentlist" />,
          ]}
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

App.displayName = "App";

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App);
```

Comment: Can you use something else instead of `useNavigation`? For example `withRouter`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use `<Navigate>` instead of `<Redirect>`.

According to the [release info](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.3), `Redirect` was removed in v6.0.0-alpha.3 (but as this is still alpha, I can imagine it was already broken in alpha.1). It also describes the reason for the removal:

> React won't let us change the state in an ancestor component on the
> initial render w/out warning, so we had to remove the 
> component, as well as the ability to do a navigate() on the initial
> render. You can still render a , but it won't actually
> update the page until the next render.
>
> If you really need to redirect on the initial render, you can either
> a) do it on your server (probably best, so it can be cached at the
> HTTP level instead of doing it in every user's browser) or b) do it
> outside of React Router (e.g. using the history API directly).

So it is **not possible** to use both `Redirect` and `useNavigate`.

But there is a [migration guide V5 to V6](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md), which states that you need to [use `<Navigate>` instead of `<Redirect>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#use-navigate-instead-of-history):

> If you prefer to use a declarative API for navigation (ala v5's
> `Redirect` component), v6 provides a `Navigate` component. Use it like:
>
> ```
> import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
>
> function App() {
>     return <Navigate to="/home" replace state={state} />;
> }
> ```